# Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 17 column 9

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument

upload any file upto 2 gb from content version

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/DragAndDrop/v1/*')
global with sharing class DragAndDropRESTAPI
{

    @HttpPost
    global static String attachDoc(){
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;

        String fName = req.params.get('FileName');
        String parId = req.params.get('parId');
        Blob postContent = req.requestBody; 
        System.debug('###'+fName);
        System.debug('@@@'+parId);
        ContentVersion CV;
        CV = new ContentVersion(versionData = postContent,Title = fName);
        for(ContentVersion atm : [select Id, VersionData from contentversion where Id = :CV.contentDocumentId]) {
            insert atm;
            return atm.Id;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to this

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/DragAndDrop/v1/*')
    global with sharing class DragAndDropRESTAPI
    {

        @HttpPost
        global static String attachDoc(){
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;

            String fName = req.params.get('FileName');
            String parId = req.params.get('parId');
            Blob postContent = req.requestBody; 
            System.debug('###'+fName);
            System.debug('@@@'+parId);
            ContentVersion CV;
            CV = new ContentVersion(versionData = postContent,Title = fName);
            for(ContentVersion atm : [select Id, VersionData from contentversion where Id = :CV.contentDocumentId]) {
                insert atm;
                return atm.Id;
           }
    return null;
       }
    }
```